# How to create a php polygon array from stored database multi-coordinates?

Tags: php, arrays

I have polygon multi-coordinates of variable points number stored on MySQL DB in the form of:

```
(73.34545, 22.58899), 
(73.34567, 22.55656), 
(73.34356, 22.51233), 
(73.34123, 22.52445)
```

I want to create a polygon array in the following form out of the previous xy coordinates:

```
$polygon = array(
    new Point(73.34545,22.58899), 
    new Point(73.34567,22.55656),
    new Point(73.34356,22.51233),
    new Point(73.34123,22.52445)
);
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which part do you need help with: connecting to the database? Retrieving the results? Creating an array from the results? Which part?

Comment: Creating an array from the results. thanks

Comment: @mdamia, Sorry what do you mean ?

Comment: @user2985035 sorry about, i pressed enter before finishing my comment. Create your own function that appends new POINT to each coordinates.

Comment: Ok, any idea about that ? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for something like this:

```
class Point {
    private $x;
    private $y;

    public function __construct($x,$y) {
           $this->x = $x;
           $this->y = $y;
    }

    public function get_coordinates() {
         return array($x,$y);
    }       
}

$polygon = array( new Point(73.34545,22.58899), new Point(73.34567,22.55656), new Point(73.34356,22.51233), new Point(73.34123,22.52445) );
```

Comment: I wanna know how to compose the... $polygon = array( new Point(73.34545,22.58899), new Point(73.34567,22.55656), new Point(73.34356,22.51233), new Point(73.34123,22.52445) );  from the DB results first

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by compose?

Comment: I mean create. Ok can you give me an example. thanks

Comment: I expected the solution to be a loop to populate the array according to the number of points in each different polygon

Answer (score 0):

although I haven't tried executing the following code but hope you would understand what I am trying to do.

```
    $database_value = (73.34545, 22.58899), (73.34567, 22.55656), (73.34356, 22.51233), (73.34123, 22.52445);

    $co_ordinates = explode(",",$database_value);
    foreach($co_ordinates as $co_ordinate){
        $co_ordinate = str_replace("(","",$co_ordinate);
        $co_ordinate = str_replace(")","",$co_ordinate);
        $co_ordinate_array = explode(",", $co_ordinate);
        $polygon[] = new Point($co_ordinate_array[0],$co_ordinate_array[1]);
    }
```

Comment: I'm applying it to the following class: class Point {
    public $lat;
    public $long;
    function Point($lat, $long) {
        $this->lat = $lat;
        $this->long = $long;
    }
}

Comment: why giving me the following results:  Array ( [0] => Point Object ( [lat] => 73.34545 [long] => ) [1] => Point Object ( [lat] => 22.58899 [long] => ) [2] => Point Object ( [lat] => 73.34567 [long] => ) [3] => Point Object ( [lat] => 22.55656 [long] => ) [4] => Point Object ( [lat] => 73.34356 [long] => ) [5] => Point Object ( [lat] => 22.51233 [long] => ) [6] => Point Object ( [lat] => 73.34123 [long] => ) [7] => Point Object ( [lat] => 22.52445 [long] => ) )

Comment: While the result should be like this: Array ( [0] => Point Object ( [lat] => 73.34545 [long] => 22.55656 ) [1] => Point Object ( [lat] => 73.34567 [long] => 22.55656 ) [2] => Point Object ( [lat] => 73.34356 [long] => 22.51233) [3] => Point Object ( [lat] => 24.558365231396 [long] => 46.627349853516 ) [4] => Point Object ( [lat] => 73.34545[long] => 46.858062744141 ) [5] => Point Object ( [lat] => 73.34123 [long] => 22.58899 ) )

Comment: check the array `$co_ordinate_array` It should contain both the co ordinates and use them accordingly

Comment: @user2985035 if your problem is solved please accept the answer as correct answer.

Comment: I checked the $co_ordinate_array it is giving me only one value ?! .. Array ( [0] => 22.52445 ) , I'm now confused more!! Plz I need your help

Comment: Did you tried the updated answer does it solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

@user2985035 try the updated code this would work

```
    $database_value = "(73.34545, 22.58899), (73.34567, 22.55656), (73.34356, 22.51233), (73.34123, 22.52445)";
    $co_ordinates_stripped = explode("), (", $database_value);
    $co_ordinates = str_replace(")", "", str_replace("(", "", $co_ordinates_stripped));

    foreach ($co_ordinates as $co_ordinate) {
        $co_ordinate = str_replace("(", "", $co_ordinate);
        $co_ordinate = str_replace(")", "", $co_ordinate);
        $co_ordinate_array = explode(",", $co_ordinate);
        $polygon[] = new Point($co_ordinate_array[0], $co_ordinate_array[1]);
    }
```